# Multiple If conditions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Have javascript function who check input value and if requiment inputs ar note lenght 0 sent ajax post.

```
    function sendEmail(){
            var nn = jQuery("#your-name").val().length;
            var ee = jQuery("#friend-email").val().length;

            // var n = document.getElementById("your-name").value;
            // var e = document.getElementById("friend-email").value;

            if ( nn == 0 && ee == 0 ) {

                jQuery("input#your-name").css("border", "1px red solid");
                jQuery("input#friend-email").css("border", "1px red solid");

            } 
            else if (ee == 0) {

                jQuery("input#friend-email").css("border", "1px red solid");

            }

            else if ( nn == 0 ) {

                jQuery("input#friend-name").css("border", "1px red solid");

            }
            else {

                ajax();
            }
}
```

Everything works well, exept: If email is set and name is is not..Nothing happens (jQuery("input#friend-name").css("border", "1px red solid");)

Whats wrong on this?
See full example in jsfidle: http://jsfiddle.net/4X2J8/

Comment: Why `#friend-name` in the last `else if` when you're using `#your-name` at the top and in the first `if` condition?

Comment: Your fiddle example is pointless, because you did not even embed jQuery there …

Comment: @Mat Because i need check if both: email and name input are set

Comment: @KārlisMillers: you're checking the length of one thing, and setting the color of some other thing.

Comment: Thanks, i undesrtand my mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should correct name field's id:  "friend-name" to "your-name".

```
  function sendEmail(){
        var nn = jQuery("#your-name").val().length;
        var ee = jQuery("#friend-email").val().length;
        // var n = document.getElementById("your-name").value;
        // var e = document.getElementById("friend-email").value;
        if ( nn == 0 && ee == 0 ) {
            jQuery("input#your-name").css("border", "1px red solid");
            jQuery("input#friend-email").css("border", "1px red solid");
        } 
        else if (ee == 0) {
            jQuery("input#friend-email").css("border", "1px red solid");
        }
        else if ( nn == 0 ) {
            jQuery("input#your-name").css("border", "1px red solid");
        }
        else {
            ajax();
        }
    }
```